# git fsck : Cannot fix broken link

Tags: git, git-fsck

I cannot succeed fixing a git broken link.

Here is the context :

```bash
$ git pull
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
warning: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c header
fatal: loose object 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c (stored in .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c) is corrupt
fatal: failed to run repack

Already up to date.
$ git fsck
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
error: 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5766/5766), done.
Checking connectivity: 12924, done.
dangling tree bd85f5cb37f9545d81b7f923978f97c4eaf391ea
dangling tree 978c24540576bfa8d0e748a33e2457c6286a0d64
dangling blob 0d91b9e2423b61d3f941a3571f08459e3f7db21f
dangling blob 4c4112f5aaa60d99ef2c8a4bb66e855eb1bac7e6
missing tree 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
$ git cat-file -t 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c header
fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info
$ du .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
0   .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
```

So I removed this empty file according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647691/5649639) :

```bash
$ rm .git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
rm: remove write-protected regular file '.git/objects/9a/684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c'? y
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5766/5766), done.
broken link from  commit fca8efc10a91c7ac2cd0acf5d6744c1cb1ea9765
              to    tree 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
Checking connectivity: 12924, done.
dangling tree bd85f5cb37f9545d81b7f923978f97c4eaf391ea
dangling tree 978c24540576bfa8d0e748a33e2457c6286a0d64
dangling blob 0d91b9e2423b61d3f941a3571f08459e3f7db21f
dangling blob 4c4112f5aaa60d99ef2c8a4bb66e855eb1bac7e6
missing tree 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
```

So I tried the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876512/how-can-i-fix-a-git-error-broken-link-from-tree-to-tree) :

```bash
$ git gc --aggressive
fatal: bad tree object 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
fatal: failed to run repack
$ git stash clear
$ git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
fatal: bad tree object 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c
fatal: failed to run repack
$ git fsck --name-objects
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5766/5766), done.
broken link from  commit fca8efc10a91c7ac2cd0acf5d6744c1cb1ea9765 (~11)
              to    tree 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c (~11:)
Checking connectivity: 12924, done.
dangling tree bd85f5cb37f9545d81b7f923978f97c4eaf391ea
dangling tree 978c24540576bfa8d0e748a33e2457c6286a0d64
dangling blob 0d91b9e2423b61d3f941a3571f08459e3f7db21f
dangling blob 4c4112f5aaa60d99ef2c8a4bb66e855eb1bac7e6
missing tree 9a684a736e3b97ff7c709138259196fd223e661c (~11:)
$
```

Comment: This is a *damaged repository*. There are no Git tools for *fixing* one; in general, most people just throw them away and re-clone. If that's not suitable for some reason, you can find help for doing certain hand-fixes, but "bad tree object" is a difficult one.

Answer (score 1):

Beside trying to [fix a corrupted repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69085374/6309), make sure to use Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)

See [commit 7c89855](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c898554d7a80e5d70ee8816a23dc425d2f1729c), [commit 4627c67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4627c67fa68d5669be511962a6437a11c0db3c99), [commit 29d8e21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29d8e21d6e97d5363233a960e7730e0afc26a8b1), [commit 58407e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58407e041e62a221d2ac823a42c41b23b2aa984b) (12 May 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b8138f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b8138fb0880e399dcb6fcc6b6d4081c1a1db40e), 23 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`object-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4627c67fa68d5669be511962a6437a11c0db3c99): fix a `unpack_loose_header()` regression in 3b6a8db3b03
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a regression in my [3b6a8db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b6a8db3b03adb118bfafb90bbc710068dbd6d14) (`object-file.c`: use , 2021-10-01, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/061a21d36d807bdcf996f388d5e487d5e1993bbc) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9)) ([`object-file.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4627c67fa68d5669be511962a6437a11c0db3c99/object-file.c): use "`enum`" return type for `unpack_loose_header()`, 2021-10-01) revealed both by running the test suite with `--valgrind`, and with the amended "[`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4627c67fa68d5669be511962a6437a11c0db3c99/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> test.
>
> **In practice this regression in v2.34.0 caused us to claim that we couldn't parse the header, as opposed to not being able to unpack it**.
>
> Before the change in the C code the `test_cmp` added here would emit:
>
> ```
> -error: unable to unpack header of ./objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
> +error: unable to parse header of ./objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
> ```
>
> I.e.
> we'd proceed to call `parse_loose_header()` on the uninitialized "hdr" value, and it would have been very unlikely for that uninitialized memory to be a valid git object.
>
> The other callers of `unpack_loose_header()` were already checking the enum values exhaustively.
> See [3b6a8db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b6a8db3b03adb118bfafb90bbc710068dbd6d14) and [5848fb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5848fb11acd0b6aad6ba9e3e71bd91485e0d4c71) (`object-file.c`: return ULHR_TOO_LONG on , 2021-10-01, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/061a21d36d807bdcf996f388d5e487d5e1993bbc) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9)) ([`object-file.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4627c67fa68d5669be511962a6437a11c0db3c99/object-file.c): return `ULHR_TOO_LONG` on "`header too long`", 2021-10-01).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you know of a Launchpad PPA to install an up to date git release ?

Comment: @SebMa Try [what I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309) for Git ppa upgrade. But 2.37 isn't released yet.